# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Livechat_Helper_Data' not found in /home/xxxx/public_html/website_name/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento

I am getting this error when I click on Add new role in

System -> Permissions -> Role

Comment: As pointer to what's wrong with the question, you need to add the code where the error occurs. Have another go at editing your question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Go to system - tool - compilation and run the compilation and logout from admin and login again. Hope its will not show any error.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is due to Magento trying to instantiate a class alias that no longer exists in the system.  This can happen for myriad reasons

1. You've partially uninstalled an extension and there's old cod lying around
2. An extension stored class information in the database and Magento used this information to try and instantiate a class
3. You've written custom code in the system that does something similar.

Magento says it's trying to instantiate a `Mage_Livechat_Helper_Data` class.  There is no `Mage_Livechat` module that ships with Magento.  This **probably** means the code you're looking for looks like

```
Mage::getModel('SOMESTRING/livechat');

<sometag module="livechat">
```

I'd do a text search of your code base (and possibly database) for "livechat".  Once you have a list of all the references to this string, it will be easier to debug why this is happening.

Comment: where do I search for it?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error.

```
> [Tue Feb 16 17:15:17 2016] [error] [client 79.150.xxx.2] PHP Fatal
> error:  Class 'Mage_Livechat_Helper_Data' not found in
> /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 547, referer:
> http://domain/index.php/xxx/permissions_role/index/key/5046d5c1da61c6d4e6492d511ed7bd2a/
```

Just uninstall Tawk.to (livechat) extension from backend trought Magento Connect. You don't need install backend extension, all is configured on [tawk.to dashboard](https://www.tawk.to/).

Hope it works for you,

Alex